# Azure Services no longer deactivating when reaching my Azure Spending Limit

Tags: azure

I have an MSDN account which gives $150 Azure credit per month. On my Azure billing account, I've also set a spending limit of $0.

Sometimes, I spin up a few machines for what I'm working on. And find that towards the end of the month my credit is exhausted and because I have a spending limit of $0, the services are suspended.

This month, however, I've noticed that I've exceeded my credit and the VMs I've got running haven't been suspended. I've checked and my spending limit is still $0, but I also have no credit.

Has something changed with Azure policy? How can ensure I don't get charged?

Edit: I've attached 2 screenshots from my billing portal showing the account does have a spending limit and no credit attached to it.

[Azure Billing Portal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlIWH.png)

[Active Services on Azure showing cost > credit balance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXAmr.png)

Comment: You could create a alter notification, when you reach the limit you set, Azure will send e-mail to you. This can prevent your costs from exceeding the standard

Comment: Please have a look at https://serverfault.com/help/merging-accounts and merge your accounts, so that you'll be able to edit your own post.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because billing and licensing questions are off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, you've probably removed the spending limit. Navigate to [https://accounts.windowsazure.com](http://accounts.windowsazure.com), click subscriptions and check if your MSDN subscription has an alert like the one of the image below:

[image]

Click on the message and you should have the option to turn it back on for the next billing cycle. This is the option at the moment that guarantees your account will be disabled in case you exceeds your credit balance.